# Symfony Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DataBundle\Entity\Location could not be converted to string

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, crud

I am trying to create a little CRUD system with 2 entities and a OneToMany relationship between these 2 entities.

My entities are Location & Job. I created the entities and created the crud controller via doctrine for both.

Location CRUD works great but Job only Read & Delete works. When I try to create a new Job it throws the following exception:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DataBundle\Entity\Location
>   could not be converted to string

I have no idea what it means or what is causing it.

If anyone could help me out that would be realy awesome!

Many thanks in advance!

Here is my code.

Entities:

Location

```
<?php

namespace DataBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Location
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="location")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="DataBundle\Repository\LocationRepository")
 */
class Location
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="street", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $street;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="number", type="string", length=25)
     */
    private $number;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="postalcode", type="string", length=4)
     */
    private $postalcode;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @var Job[] Available jobs for this location.
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Job", mappedBy="location")
     */
    private $jobs;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->jobs = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Location
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set street
     *
     * @param string $street
     *
     * @return Location
     */
    public function setStreet($street)
    {
        $this->street = $street;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get street
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStreet()
    {
        return $this->street;
    }

    /**
     * Set number
     *
     * @param string $number
     *
     * @return Location
     */
    public function setNumber($number)
    {
        $this->number = $number;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get number
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNumber()
    {
        return $this->number;
    }

    /**
     * Set postalcode
     *
     * @param string $postalcode
     *
     * @return Location
     */
    public function setPostalcode($postalcode)
    {
        $this->postalcode = $postalcode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get postalcode
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPostalcode()
    {
        return $this->postalcode;
    }

    /**
     * Set city
     *
     * @param string $city
     *
     * @return Location
     */
    public function setCity($city)
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get city
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    /**
     * Add job
     *
     * @param \DataBundle\Entity\Job $job
     *
     * @return Location
     */
    public function addJob(\DataBundle\Entity\Job $job)
    {
        $this->jobs[] = $job;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove job
     *
     * @param \DataBundle\Entity\Job $job
     */
    public function removeJob(\DataBundle\Entity\Job $job)
    {
        $this->jobs->removeElement($job);
    }

    /**
     * Get jobs
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getJobs()
    {
        return $this->jobs;
    }
}
```

Job:

```
<?php

namespace DataBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Job
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="job")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="DataBundle\Repository\JobRepository")
 */
class Job
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var Location
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Location", inversedBy="jobs")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="location_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $location;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     *
     * @return Job
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Job
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set location
     *
     * @param \DataBundle\Entity\Location $location
     *
     * @return Job
     */
    public function setLocation(\DataBundle\Entity\Location $location = null)
    {
        $this->location = $location;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get location
     *
     * @return \DataBundle\Entity\Location
     */
    public function getLocation()
    {
        return $this->location;
    }
}
```

My new action in the JobController:

```
    /**
     * Creates a new job entity.
     *
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $job = new Job();
        $form = $this->createForm('DataBundle\Form\JobType', $job);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($job);
            $em->flush($job);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('job_show', array('id' => $job->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('job/new.html.twig', array(
            'job' => $job,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

DataBundle/Form/JobTypep

```
<?php

namespace DataBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class JobType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('title')->add('description')->add('location')        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'DataBundle\Entity\Job'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'databundle_job';
    }
}
```

Comment: Add code for DataBundle\Form\JobType. I think that you use location field as string in this form.

Comment: The error say that you are trying to convert an object to an array. For example, instead of doing {{ object.id }}, you are doing {{ object }}

Comment: @MaxP. I edited OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `location` as text field in your form, location is object.

You can fix this error by using form data transformers that will convert location into text on form output and text in location object on form submit.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html

Or by using form type `EnityType` for location:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('title')->add('description');

    $builder
        ->add('location', Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => false,
            'class' => 'DataBundle\\Entity\\Location',
            'empty_data' => '',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'label' => 'Location',
        ]);
}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Comment: Okay I think I understand but now on the /job/new page I can only select a location but I have no form for the Title & Description of a Job

Comment: I've updated my answer, I think that you have removed `title` and `description` from form builder.